# Python reading csv file inside a subfolder in a zipped folder

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I am trying the following:

```
import pandas as pd
loc = r'T:\Analysis\calibraer19.zip\col1\profiles\myfile.csv'
pd.read_csv(loc)
```

But I keep getting file not exists error. I am not sure how to read this file as the zip folder size is very large with 100s of files in it so unzipping is not a good option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `zipfile` library to extract only the file you want to read:

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile(r'T:\Analysis\calibraer19.zip') as z:
    with open('myfile.csv', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(z.read(r'col1\profiles\myfile.csv'))

df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following approach with `zipfile` module:

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile("Desktop.zip") as z:
    data = z.read("pandas_test_data.csv").decode("utf-8-sig")

lines = (elem for elem in data.split("\r\n")) 

# lines = (elem for elem in data.split("\n")) if you're csv contains \n instead of \r\n

rows_of_data = (elem.split(",") for elem in lines)

df = pd.DataFrame(rows_of_data)
```

You read the data once and then simply create generators for subsequent steps. The generators can be consumed by the pandas DataFrame class's constructor.

Note: I added the `decode("utf-8-sig")` since i have encountered UTF-BOM characters when reading Zip Files.